# Nutch 2.1 urls injection takes forever

Tags: apache, nutch

I'm trying to deploy nutch 2.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 by following that [tutorial](https://github.com/renepickhardt/metalcon/wiki/simpleNutchSolrSetup/). Everything goes well
until I try to inject urls into the database. When I type ($bin/nutch inject urls) and press
Enter I get

```
    InjectorJob: starting
    InjectorJob: urlDir: urls
```

and remains there (for hours) until I decide to cancel the execution. urls is a directory
that contains file with urls.  I added proxy and port details in the nutch-site.xml as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586950/nutch-2-2-1-doesnt-continue-after-injector-job?answertab=active#tab-top/) but it doesn't solve. I tried apache nutch 2.2.1 and the issue continues.

If you know how to fix that issue, please, help me!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu defaults the loopback IP address in hosts to 127.0.1.1. HBase (according to [this page](http://hbase.apache.org/book/quickstart.html)) requires your loopback IP address be 127.0.0.1.

The Ubuntu `/etc/hosts` file by default contains (with myComputerName being your computer name):

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   myComputerName
```

Use `sudo gedit /etc/hosts` to update your hosts file as follow:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   myComputerName
```

Reboot Ubuntu. Nutch should no longer have trouble injecting urls into HBase.