# Nutch2.3.1 hangs while inject, parse fetch, generate

Tags: solr, hbase, nutch, gora

I've read various SO threads on why it takes so long (or hangs) while generating/injecting/parsing/fetching, but to no luck. The solutions in the following SO threads I've tried implementing, but no luck.

1) [Nutch 2.1 urls injection takes forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050000/nutch-2-1-urls-injection-takes-forever)

2) [Nutch 2.2.1 doesnt continue after Injector job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586950/nutch-2-2-1-doesnt-continue-after-injector-job?lq=1)

and various other threads.

I'm using Nutch2.3.1 and HBase0.94.27. I've been following [this](https://qbox.io/blog/scraping-the-web-with-nutch-for-elasticsearch) and [this](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Tutorial) tutorial and I was able to build successfully. But when I fire any nutch commands, it hangs up.

Following are the logs I get while firing these commands:-

**Inject Command**

```
root@ubuntu:~/apache-nutch-2.3.1/runtime/local# ./bin/nutch inject seed/urls.txt 
InjectorJob: starting at 2016-05-04 09:59:12
InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: seed/urls.txt
```

**Generate Command**

```
root@ubuntu:~/apache-nutch-2.3.1/runtime/local# bin/nutch generate -topN 40
GeneratorJob: starting at 2016-05-04 09:54:08
GeneratorJob: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.
GeneratorJob: starting
GeneratorJob: filtering: true
GeneratorJob: normalizing: true
GeneratorJob: topN: 40
```

**Fetch command**

```
root@ubuntu:~/apache-nutch-2.3.1/runtime/local# bin/nutch fetch -all
FetcherJob: starting at 2016-05-04 10:00:14
FetcherJob: fetching all
FetcherJob: threads: 10
FetcherJob: parsing: false
FetcherJob: resuming: false
FetcherJob : timelimit set for : -1
```

**Parse Command**

```
root@ubuntu:~/apache-nutch-2.3.1/runtime/local# bin/nutch parse -all
ParserJob: starting at 2016-05-04 10:00:43
ParserJob: resuming:    false
ParserJob: forced reparse:      false
ParserJob: parsing all
```

**Update Command**

```
root@ubuntu:~/apache-nutch-2.3.1/runtime/local# bin/nutch updatedb -all
DbUpdaterJob: starting at 2016-05-04 10:02:24
DbUpdaterJob: updatinging all
```

Following is the HBase logs:-

```
 client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:45216
2016-05-04 10:00:47,214 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: caught end of stream exception
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x1547b2be4bc000e, likely client has closed socket
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:220)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-05-04 10:00:47,215 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:45216 which had sessionid 0x1547b2be4bc000e
2016-05-04 10:00:47,215 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: caught end of stream exception
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x1547b2be4bc000d, likely client has closed socket
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:220)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-05-04 10:00:47,216 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:59934 which had sessionid 0x1547b2be4bc000d
2016-05-04 10:01:10,000 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Expiring session 0x1547b2be4bc000c, timeout of 40000ms exceeded
2016-05-04 10:01:10,001 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x1547b2be4bc000c
2016-05-04 10:01:22,002 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Expiring session 0x1547b2be4bc000b, timeout of 40000ms exceeded
2016-05-04 10:01:22,003 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x1547b2be4bc000b
2016-05-04 10:01:28,001 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Expiring session 0x1547b2be4bc000e, timeout of 40000ms exceeded
2016-05-04 10:01:28,001 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Expiring session 0x1547b2be4bc000d, timeout of 40000ms exceeded
2016-05-04 10:01:28,001 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x1547b2be4bc000e
2016-05-04 10:01:28,001 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x1547b2be4bc000d
2016-05-04 10:02:25,195 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:59938
2016-05-04 10:02:25,202 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:59938
2016-05-04 10:02:25,204 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Established session 0x1547b2be4bc000f with negotiated timeout 40000 for client /127.0.0.1:59938
2016-05-04 10:02:25,822 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:59940
2016-05-04 10:02:25,822 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:59940
2016-05-04 10:02:25,825 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Established session 0x1547b2be4bc0010 with negotiated timeout 40000 for client /127.0.0.1:59940
2016-05-04 10:04:15,530 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.LruBlockCache: Stats: total=2.02 MB, free=243.82 MB, max=245.84 MB, blocks=3, accesses=27, hits=24, hitRatio=88.88%, , cachingAccesses=27, cachingHits=24, cachingHitsRatio=88.88%, , evictions=0, evicted=0, evictedPerRun=NaN
2016-05-04 10:04:28,372 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner: Scanning .META. starting at row= for max=2147483647 rows using org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation@25e5c862
2016-05-04 10:04:28,379 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.CatalogJanitor: Scanned 0 catalog row(s) and gc'd 0 unreferenced parent region(s)
2016-05-04 10:09:15,530 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.LruBlockCache: Stats: total=2.02 MB, free=243.82 MB, max=245.84 MB, blocks=3, accesses=27, hits=24, hitRatio=88.88%, , cachingAccesses=27, cachingHits=24, cachingHitsRatio=88.88%, , evictions=0, evicted=0, evictedPerRun=NaN
```

**Hadoop.log**

```
2016-05-04 10:42:18,132 INFO  crawl.InjectorJob - InjectorJob: starting at 2016-05-04 10:42:18
2016-05-04 10:42:18,134 INFO  crawl.InjectorJob - InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: seed/urls.txt
2016-05-04 10:42:18,527 WARN  util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

What exactly is the problem. I have configured everything correctly and it still hangs up. **Why**

Comment: Have you tried disabling ipv6 and use only ipv4 in Hadoop + HBase?

Comment: I'm now using Mongo as a replacement for HBase, reason being Hadoop+HBase being too complex. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I'm now getting an error while indexing the data into the ES. Here's the question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052674/nutch-elasticsearch-integration . Can you please provide any info on the same.