# Nutch Elasticsearch Integration

Tags: elasticsearch, nutch

I'm following [this](http://www.aossama.com/search-engine-with-apache-nutch-mongodb-and-elasticsearch/) tutorial for setting up nutch alongwith Elasticsearch. Whenever I try to index the data into the ES, it returns an error. Following are the logs:-

**Command:-**

```
bin/nutch index elasticsearch -all
```

Logs when I add `elastic.port`(9200) in `conf/nutch-site.xml` :-

```
2016-05-05 13:22:49,903 INFO  basic.BasicIndexingFilter - Maximum title length for indexing set to: 100
2016-05-05 13:22:49,904 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.basic.BasicIndexingFilter
2016-05-05 13:22:49,904 INFO  anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter - Anchor deduplication is: off
2016-05-05 13:22:49,904 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter
2016-05-05 13:22:49,905 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.metadata.MetadataIndexer
2016-05-05 13:22:49,906 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.more.MoreIndexingFilter
2016-05-05 13:22:49,961 INFO  elastic.ElasticIndexWriter - Processing remaining requests [docs = 0, length = 0, total docs = 0]
2016-05-05 13:22:49,961 INFO  elastic.ElasticIndexWriter - Processing to finalize last execute
2016-05-05 13:22:54,898 INFO  client.transport - [Peggy Carter] failed to get node info for [#transport#-1][ubuntu][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]], disconnecting...
org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]][cluster:monitor/nodes/info] request_id [1] timed out after [5000ms]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:366)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-05-05 13:22:55,682 INFO  indexer.IndexWriters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.elastic.ElasticIndexWriter
2016-05-05 13:22:55,683 INFO  indexer.IndexingJob - Active IndexWriters :
ElasticIndexWriter
        elastic.cluster : elastic prefix cluster
        elastic.host : hostname
        elastic.port : port  (default 9300)
        elastic.index : elastic index command 
        elastic.max.bulk.docs : elastic bulk index doc counts. (default 250) 
        elastic.max.bulk.size : elastic bulk index length. (default 2500500 ~2.5MB)


2016-05-05 13:22:55,711 INFO  elasticsearch.plugins - [Adrian Toomes] loaded [], sites []
2016-05-05 13:23:00,763 INFO  client.transport - [Adrian Toomes] failed to get node info for [#transport#-1][ubuntu][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:92$0]], disconnecting...
org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]][cluster:monitor/nodes/info] request_id [0] time$ out after [5000ms]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:366)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-05-05 13:23:00,766 INFO  indexer.IndexingJob - IndexingJob: done.
```

Logs when default port 9300 is used:-

```
2016-05-05 13:58:44,584 INFO  elasticsearch.plugins - [Mentallo] loaded [], sites []
2016-05-05 13:58:44,673 WARN  transport.netty - [Mentallo] Message not fully read (response) for [0] handler future(org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SimpleNodeSampler$1@3c80f1dd), error [true], resetting
2016-05-05 13:58:44,674 INFO  client.transport - [Mentallo] failed to get node info for [#transport#-1][ubuntu][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:9300]], disconnecting...
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: Failed to deserialize exception response from stream
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportSerializationException: Failed to deserialize exception response from stream
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:173)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:125)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: Unsupported version: 1
        at org.elasticsearch.common.io.ThrowableObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ThrowableObjectInputStream.java:46)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:301)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.io.ThrowableObjectInputStream.<init>(ThrowableObjectInputStream.java:38)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:170)
        ... 23 more
2016-05-05 13:58:44,676 INFO  indexer.IndexingJob - IndexingJob: done.
```

I've configured everything fine. Have had a look at various threads as well but to no avail. Also java version for both ES and JVM is same. Is there a bug in here?

I'm using Nutch 2.3.1 and have tried with both ES 1.4.4 and 2.3.2. I can see data in Mongo but I cannot index data in ES. Why??

Comment: What is the result of curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200'

Comment: The same default json. "You know for search".

Comment: Can you reach 9200 port for example via telnet?

Comment: Yes. `telnet localhost 9200` gives me an output saying `Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.`

Comment: That possible a version problem. In source nutch uses ES version 1.4.1 as dependency. May be you can try to use that version.

Comment: ES 1.4.1 with Nutch2.3.1?

Comment: But I would like to use the current version of ES because of its many upgraded functionalities. Though I can give a try with ES1.4.1

Comment: Yeah checkout that: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/nutch/trunk/src/plugin/indexer-elastic/ivy.xml?revision=1644797&view=markup

Comment: I tried indexing data with 1.4.1. I dont get any error now. But data is not injected to ES either.

Comment: What can be the possible error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111153/discussion-between-alpert-and-pythonenthusiast).