# Nutch (2.2.1) Inject Urls Hangs

Tags: solr, hbase, nutch, ubuntu-14.04

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, I'm tying to get a basic Nutch Web Crawl running to no avail. Following [this](https://github.com/renepickhardt/metalcon/wiki/simpleNutchSolrSetup) tutorial I set up the following building blocks:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- HBase 0.90.4
- Nutch 2.2.1
- Solr 4.3.1

I confirm both HBase and Solr is running, I populate the `urls/seed.txt` file. Then when I call;

```
bin/nutch inject urls
```

I'm presented with the following output and then it seems Nutch just hangs.

```
InjectorJob: starting at 2014-06-09 23:38:49
InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: urls/seed.txt
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586950/nutch-2-2-1-doesnt-continue-after-injector-job) stackoverflow question seems similar to mine, I am however not behind a proxy so the answer is not applicable.

Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Andrew-Barber Could you please elaborate on why my question is off-topic. I feel the link to the [tutorial](https://github.com/renepickhardt/metalcon/wiki/simpleNutchSolrSetup) in combination with the exact point of failure in said tutorial and the respective Ubuntu and Nutch versions makes the question Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu defaults the loopback IP address in hosts to 127.0.1.1. HBase (according to [this page](http://hbase.apache.org/book/quickstart.html)) requires your loopback IP address be 127.0.0.1.

The Ubuntu `/etc/hosts` file by default contains (with myComputerName being your computer name):

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   myComputerName
```

Use `sudo gedit /etc/hosts` to update your hosts file as follow:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   myComputerName
```

Reboot Ubuntu. Nutch should no longer have trouble injecting urls into HBase.

Comment: I have followed same thing updated this also still mine is not working.